# Spring Integration EnableIntegrationManagement plus MetricRegistry

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, metrics

I've read about the new feature in Spring Integration `4.2.0.RELEASE` for capturing counts and stats on channels and handlers via the `@EnableIntegrationManagement` annotation and `MetricsFactory` implementations, here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.2.0.RELEASE/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html.

I'm also aware of a pending update here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/pull/1568.

I see that there is MBean export capability, but I'd really like to surface the counts and stats via Spring Boot actuator's `/metrics` endpoint.  It's not clear to me how I might go about doing this.  Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated.  My initial thought is to extend `AggregatingMetricsFactory` an plumb in an instance of `MetricRegistry`. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The counts are enabled via JMX (when enabled) for backwards compatibility.

However, it's no longer necessary to enable JMX to get stats when using `@EnableIntegrationManagement`.

You can simply use `context.getBeansOftype()` to get all beans (`MessageChannelMetrics`, `MessageHandlerMetrics`, `MessageSourceMetrics`) and expose those stats that you are interested in by iterating over the instances.

Comment: Gary, I came up with this:  https://gist.github.com/fastnsilver/f24e6172ea90e7f829b6. I'd be happy to work it into an auto-config.  Let me know if there's any interest.

Comment: I suggest you use the bean name (keys in the map) instead of the class name. I also suggest you open an issue in [the boot github repo](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) and discuss it with the boot guys; it looks like there's some existing work there based on the JMX MBean exporter; see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-actuator/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/actuate/metrics/integration/SpringIntegrationMetricReader.java).

Comment: Thanks again Gary.  I have updated my gist per your recommendation.  I have also logged https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/4031.